# PHP use __get to call a method?

Tags: php, class, delegation

I've got some PHP cruft that I would like to delegate methods. Sort of a poor-man's mixin.

Basically I would like the following:

```
<?php

class Apprentice
{
    public function magic() {
        echo 'Abracadabra!';
    }
}

class Sourcerer // I work magic with the source
{
    private $apprentice;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->apprentice = new Apprentice();
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        if (method_exists($this->apprentice, $key)) {
            return $this->apprentice->{$key};
        }
        throw Exception("no magic left");
    }
}

$source = new Sourcerer();
$source->magic();
?>
```

To not throw a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Sourcerer::magic() in .../test__get.php`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public function __call($name, $args) {
    if (method_exists($this->apprentice, $name)) {
        return $this->apprentice->$name($args);
    }
    throw Exception("no magic left");
}
```

**ps:** use `__call` for methods as `__get` is only for properties.
And yes, it is better to use `call_user_func_array`, otherwise arguments are supplied as array to the `magic` function.

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this->apprentice, $name), $args);
```

Comment: This++. __call is what you're really looking for.  Additionally, you might want to investigate __callStatic if you ever want to use this kind of functionality in a static function in the future.

Comment: Ohhh... I misread the docs entirely, I thought `__call()` was for calling an instance as though it were a function, that it was for implementing `$s = new S(); $s();`. Thanks!

Comment: @quodlibetor the method [`__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) is for calling an instance as though it were a function.

Answer (score 3):

1. To actually call the method on `apprentice`, you'll have to actually call it like so:

   ```
   return $this->apprentice->$key();
   ```
2. You're using `$source->magic()`, which does not invoke the `__get` method. `__get` is for variable access like `$source->magic`, but `$source->magic()` is a function call. If you want a magic method for function calls, that's `__call`.

Answer (score 2):

More like `__call` instead of `__get` in your case:

```
class Sourcerer // I work magic with the source
{
    private $apprentice;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->apprentice = new Apprentice();
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (method_exists($this->apprentice, $name)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->apprentice, $name), $arguments);
        }
        throw Exception("no magic left");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call would instead be:

```
$source = new Sourcerer();
$source->apprentice->magic();
```

Also, I believe the `__get()` magic method works on properties, not method names.

Finally, in your actual `__get()` definition, the syntax is wrong: it should be `throw new Exception('message');`. I'd also move this to an `else` clause, otherwise it's going to get triggered each call regardless, as it's outside any `if`/`else` or other logic.

Comment: you're right about the syntax, and wrong about the necessity of the `else` (the `if` has a return.) But the chain of lookups is what I'm trying to avoid.